# Using VBA to unzip file without prompting me once (choose "Yes to All" for any dialog box)

Tags: vba, excel

There is an unzipping code I'd like to adjust 4 my needs.

```
Sub Unzip()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefinePath As String

          ' Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", MultiSelect:=False)
    Fname = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl.zip"

    If Fname = False Then
          'Do nothing
    Else
          'Destination folder
       DefinePath = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl_mst\"    ' Change to your path / variable
       If Right(DefinePath, 1) <> "\" Then
           DefinePath = DefinePath & "\"
       End If

       FileNameFolder = DefinePath

        '        Delete all the files in the folder DefPath first if you want.
        '        On Error Resume Next
        '        Kill DefPath & "*.*"
        '        On Error GoTo 0

        'Extract the files into the Destination folder
       Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

        ' MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

      On Error Resume Next
      Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
      FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
   End If
End Sub
```

Somewhere here:

```
  `Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere`
```

a dialog box appears asking me if I want to overwrite the file that have the same names - and Yes I do want to overwrite them, but without answering the dialog box - I would like to hardcode it into the code, please.

[image]

I've found this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx  but I just don't know how to add this parameter #16 which is "Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed."
Can U help me with that?

And the last thing:
can You explain `oApp.Namespace(Fname).items` line for me.
I've really tried to guess it myself, but I thing I'm to short 4 this.

Comment: `oApp.Namespace(Fname)` returns a reference to the zip file (in this case synonymous with Folder) and its contents. `items` represents the contents of the zip file.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787868(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What I don't understand in this code is which line exactly unzips the file ??
And what `oApp` variable is created for ??

Comment: `oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items` copies all the items from the zip file to `FileNameFolder`.  Note that the `CopyHere` method has *options* which you can try out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx   "16" looks like the value you want, so try `oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items, 16`

Comment: ...and `oApp` is the object which has the methods you're using in your code to unzip the zip file: you need to create that object before you can use it.

Comment: Sorry I missed the part at the bottom of your post where you posted the same link I added to the MS docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that results in no questions or no prompting of any kind is as follows:

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub Bossa_Unzip()
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim oApp As Object             ' oApp is the object which has the methods you're using in your code to unzip the zip file: 
                               'you need to create that object before you can use it.
 Dim Fname As Variant
 Dim FileNameFolder As Variant     ' previously Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
 Dim DefinePath As String

' Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", MultiSelect:=False)
 Fname = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl.zip"

 If Fname = False Then
    'Do nothing
 Else
    'Destination folder
     DefinePath = "C:\Users\michal\SkyDrive\csv\bossa\mstcgl_mst\"      ' Change to your path / variable
     If Right(DefinePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefinePath = DefinePath & "\"
     End If

     FileNameFolder = DefinePath

    '        Delete all the files in the folder DefPath first if you want.
    '        On Error Resume Next
    '        Kill DefPath & "*.*"
    '        On Error GoTo 0

    'Extract the files into the Destination folder
     Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")            ' you need to create oApp object before you can use it.
               oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items, 16


     'MsgBox "You'll find the files here: " & DefinePath

     On Error Resume Next
     Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
     FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
    End If
  End Sub
```

Of course [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) helped me a lot - its `CpyHere` explanation site.

One thing I don't understand is why `Fname` and `FileNumberFolder` need to be declared as variant. In my opinion, they should be declared as String. Just look at this screenshot.

[image]

But when I declare them that way, the code gives me error.

[image]

Just look here, when the variables already have their values (first picture). The `FileNameVariable` and `DefinePath` variable have the exact same value, and it looks like a string 4 me. How is that necessary, that I need to declare another variable - `FileNameVariable` in that case (in 17th line) with the same value, but variant type.
please explain that to me, someone.

Comment: Well, depending on your IT expereience the explanation could be different. Try with this two - A) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085(v=vs.85).aspx B) - It is a variant, because the method expects a variant, and not a string. In OOP having the same method with different parameters is called `overloading`. VBA does not support it.